# Where to find chromedriver.log in selenium using java. Where can i see the log file of chromedriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to extract chrome logs in java selenium web driver project.  I am using following to launch chromedriver.

```
 > dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
 > System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logFile","//src//resource//log.txt");
```

**Another similar question has following solution.**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntries;
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntry;
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogType;
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ChromeConsoleLogging {
    private WebDriver driver;


    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");        
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
        logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
        caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    public void analyzeLog() {
        LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
        for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
            System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
            //do something useful with the data
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        driver.get("http://mypage.com");
        //do something on page
        analyzeLog();
    }
}
```

Solution is not useful for me, as I want to save browser log for every session with the session Id itself.

Comment: What is your exact requirement? Do you want browser console logs in text  file? Are you getting any exceptions? What you have tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to extract browser log in text file. 
I am not just able to figure out what is the best way to do it as I have been unsuccessful after trying many different things.

Comment: Instead of printing information in `analyzeLog()` method, you need to extract it in text file. Any challenge in that?

Comment: I have resolved the issue. I was trying to handle multiple browser, and multiple output text file. Trick was to handle each text file as separate objects.

Thank you for all the hlp.